# Finding Nerode equivalence classes

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

How am I supposed to find the equivalence classes of a Language? 
What should I think?

For instance, having a language

$$L =\{a^n b^m \mid n,m \ge 0, (m+n) \bmod2=0)\}$$

I can have:

- $[a^n]$ with $n$ even. *Whatever word i add, the word belongs to $L$*
- $[a^n]$ with $n$ odd. _There are no chances that, adding a word $z$ $i$
  obtain something that belongs to $L$ (i should add another odd number
  of letters, which is not possible). _
- $[a^nb^m]$ $n$ is even $m$ is odd or viceversa. *If and only if i add an odd number if $b$'s I obtain a word in the language.*
- $[a^nb^m]$ n is even m is even or n is odd m is odd.
  *If and only if i add an even number if b's I obtain a word in the
  language.*

Am I right?
Is there an algorithm to find this equivalence class in more general/difficult cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general way of thinking seems to be right, but your explanations of the first two equivalence classes is off.

If you have seen an even number of `a`s, it is not true that you end up in $L$ no matter what you add. For example if you have seen is `aa` and the rest of the input is `b`, the entire string `aab` is not in $L$.

Conversely, if you have seen an *odd* number of `a`s, all is not lost. For example, if you have seen `aaa`, you can still end up in $L$ if the rest of the input is `abb`.

(Are you perhaps expecting that the word you add must itself be in $L$? There's no such requirement).

In the two $\mathtt a^n\mathtt b^m$ classes you should specify that they apply only when $m\ge 1$.

There's in fact a fifth equivalence class, consisting of strings that are not prefixes of any word in $L$ such as `aaba` or `abc`.

A different way of describing the four "live" equivalence classes would be that each of them is characterized by the answers to the two questions: Have I seen an even or an odd number of symbols yet? and Have I begun seeing `b`s yet?

---

There's no *algorithm* for finding the equivalence classes when, as here, the description of the language you have to work from is a free-form human-readable description.

However, if you have a *formal* specification of a regular language (such as a regular expression, a regular grammar, or a finite automaton), then the equivalence classes correspond exactly to the reachable states of a minimized DFA, and you can use standard algorithms to construct that.